# osstringstream throws Expression must be an lvalue or a function designator error

Tags: c++

I am constructing a std::string as follows

```
std::string sErrorInfo= "";
std::string TableName= getTableName();
double* myTable = MaskTableLimit::getFunction().getAddressesByName(tableName);

sErrorInfo = tableName + " is not correctly defined. Spectrum limit on the frequency (Fc-" + static_cast<ostringstream*>(&(ostringstream() << myTable[1]))->str() + ") MHz must be equal to that of the frequency (Fc-" + static_cast<ostringstream*>(&(ostringstream() << myTable[3]))->str() + ") MHz.";`
```

and this just throws an expression must be an lvalue or function designator error when compiling with Visual Studio 2017 platform.

The error seems to be at the constructor call,

```
 &(osstringstream()->)
```

I am not able to figure out why this happens. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Here is [an example](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/PZDkJd) of what a MCVE looks like -- but mine compiles successfully , so chances are that you have some bug in your real code that is not apparent from the snippet you posted.

Comment: BTW a less cumbersome way to do the same task would be `std::to_string(myTable[1])` , or use one stringstream to build the whole string

Comment: You are right. There were return call errors with getTableName(). Had fixed it and it seems to work perfectly fine. Thank you for your alternative solution, this seems to be quite simpler :)